# Retrieving dynamic DOM content in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, dom

I am trying to scrape some content from a website, but `selenium.page_source()` does not contain all the content I need beacuse the webiste is dynamically rendered. When opening DevTools in Chrome you are able to inspect all of the DOM-elements - even those rendered dynamically. This made me believe that there must be a way in selenium to do this as well.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Please add your code and as well as the link to the website you're trying to scrape...

Comment: Is it possible to share Page URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the inner html of the html or body

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body").get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

If that does not get everything, please post the source `html/website`.